# SignalR in Azure Static Web App doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have API (.NET Core 3.1), Website (GatsbyJS) and mobile app (React Native). I'm deploying API on my Digital Ocean droplet, while website is hosted as Azure Web Static App. API is hosted on subdomain (api.mysite.com).

Locally, SignalR works fine for website and mobile. When deployed, SignalR works fine only for mobile while for web it's throwing errors. Handshake is okay but fails afterwards.

Some errors after few ways of trying to make it work:

- There was an error with the transport
- Handshake was cancelled

I tried using HTTP as well as HTTPS. Also tried to use skipNegotiation but that fails as well. I'm out of ideas on what I can try and what can be the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in configuration on Digital Ocean where API was hosted. More info how to solve websocket issue can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-3.1#linux-with-nginx